# Adding tap Gesture to a tableview makes the UICollectionView cells not selectable which are placed in the table header view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a tap gesture added to a table view for dismissing the keyboard. In order to make multiple gesture recognizing i have implemented gesture delegation. Every thing works fine. I am able to receive tap gestures and button touch gestures which are place in header view simultaneosly.

But the collection view  cell in the header is not selectable because of my tap gesture in the table view. Can any one help me on this

Comment: try and add it to the superview

Comment: i tried adding it on supeview , but still the same issue

Comment: Why not resignFirstResponder on cell selection and on UIScrollView didScroll delegate?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick `[tap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just came up with this exact problem and found a kind of solution.

So first, remove the tap gestures. Next, in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` add the following:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

And there you should have it.